# How to draw a bound and tip vortex for a simple horse shoe

Tags: tikz-pgf

am having challenges putting the dimensions and the curved arrows to a sample pictures shown below, i have little experience plotting using latex. thanks in advance
[image: i have managed to draw this, but i have challenges putting the dimensions and the curved arrows. my code looks like this]

A MWE which produces just the straight lines:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thick] (0, 0) -- (0, 6) -- (5, 6) -- (5, 0);
        \draw[very thick] (8, 0) -- (8, 3) -- (13, 3) -- (13, 0); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[very thick] (0,0)--(0,6) node{}--(5,6)--(5,0);
 \draw[very thick] (8,0)--(8,3)--(13,)--(13,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the original figure was drawn with Asymptote. Here is a TikZ version. In my opinion, the general principle of TikZ drawing is putting `node`s and `pic`s along `path`s. So this code is a good illustration for that principle.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[arcarr/.pic={\draw[-stealth,red] (-.3,0) arc(180:0:.3);}]
\def\b{2}
\draw[thick] (0,0)
--(0,2*\b) pic[midway]{arcarr}             node[midway,right=3mm]{$\Gamma$}
--(\b,2*\b) pic[midway,rotate=-90]{arcarr} node[midway,below=3mm]{$\Gamma$}
--(\b,0) pic[midway,xscale=-1]{arcarr}     node[midway,left=3mm]{$\Gamma$};
\draw[gray] (0,-.2)--(0,-.7) (\b,-.2)--(\b,-.7);
\draw[gray,<->] (0,-.5)--+(0:\b) node[midway,above,black]{$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using some macros.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\newcommand{\hquotnum}[3]{
\draw[|<->|] (0,-1 -| #1) -- (0,-1 -| #2) node[midway,above]{$#3$};}
\def\rd{5mm}
\newcommand{\rquotGamma}[4]{\draw[->] ([xshift=-\rd]$(#1)!0.5!(#2)$) arc[start angle=200,end angle=-20,radius=\rd] node[below #3]{{\Large$#4$}};}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Latex[length=4mm,width=1.5mm,bend]}]
        \draw[very thick] (0, 0) coordinate (a) -- (0, 6) coordinate (b) -- (5, 6) coordinate (c) -- (5, 0) coordinate (d);
        \draw[very thick] (8, 0) coordinate (e) -- (8, 3) coordinate (f) -- (13, 3) coordinate (g) -- (13, 0) coordinate (h);
\fill  ($(f)!0.5!(g)$) coordinate (p) circle[radius=2pt] node[above]{$P$};
\hquotnum{a}{d}{b}
\hquotnum{d}{e}{\frac{b}{2}}
\hquotnum{e}{p}{\frac{b}{2}}
\hquotnum{e}{p}{\frac{b}{2}}
\def\cshift{10mm}
\draw[|<->|] ([xshift=\cshift]c) -- ([xshift=\cshift]c |- f) node[midway,right]{$b$};
\rquotGamma{a}{b}{right}{\Gamma}
\begin{scope}[rotate=90,xscale=-1]
\rquotGamma{b}{c}{right}{\Gamma}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
\rquotGamma{c}{d}{left}{\Gamma}
\end{scope}
\rquotGamma{e}{f}{right}{}
\begin{scope}[rotate=90,xscale=-1]
\rquotGamma{p}{g}{right}{}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
\rquotGamma{g}{h}{left}{}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: scheme]

Comment: I like very much the tips of the arrows. :-) I think that you can improved your code increasing the tickness of the straight-lines, and putting \Gamma in slanted and using the newtxtext and newtxmath packages. +1